# use scanf() to store a long hex data into an array in C

Tags: arrays, input, hex, output, scanf

Here I have a question on using scanf() function. I am trying to use scanf() to capture long data in hex format, and store into an array. 
But what i can do is only enter ASCII and convert them into HEX.

For example:

```c
int main(void) 
{
    int len=28;
    unsigned char ChangedinData[28]="";
    unsigned char inData[28]="";
    unsigned char outData[28]="";

    //scan the keyboard string data
    scanf("%28s", &inData);
    printf("The inData is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", inData);

    // ASCII convert to HEX
    unsigned int i, t, hn, ln;
    for (t = 0,i = 0; i < len; i+=2,++t)
    {
        hn = inData[i] > '9' ? inData[i] - 'A' + 10 : inData[i] - '0';
        ln = inData[i+1] > '9' ? inData[i+1] - 'A' + 10 : inData[i+1] - '0';

        ChangedinData[t] = (hn << 4 ) | ln;
    }
    printf("This is ChangedinData[]\n");
    printf("%s\n", &ChangedinData[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, if I enter 3031323334353637383941424344. Then the output will be 0123456789ABCD.

How can it scan my input as a HEX data. For example I just enter a long data (0123456789abcdef01234567890abcdef). Then dump the value from the array and display on the screen in HEX format (0x0123456789abcdef01234567890abcdef) as well?

Comment: Are you actually asking "is there a printf/scanf flag that deals with hex values?"? `%x`.

Comment: well, i have tried to use int a; scanf("%x", &a); printf("%#x", a); However, this only can store 4bytes data at one time. How can I store the long data into a array?

Comment: You cannot scan into an array (except for a NULL-terminated character array), but there are modifiers to printf/scanf flags.... read the documentation on printf to learn about `%lx` for example.